# Temporary disable ordering in Drupal Commerce

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I need to temporary disable ordering until some date. So, I need to unable users to have add to cart button and unable them to go to checkout or cart.

But still I need to enable everything after this date.

How I can do this in Drupal Commerce? I'm using v7.x-1.13.

Comment: Why did you use the "rules" tag in this question?

Comment: I though that it can be done by Rules, but I didn't found the solution

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do would be to disable "Access checkout" permission for these non-privileged users. That may result in some usability issues where links appear that would be inaccessible, so you'll want to confirm that and adjust those interfaces appropriately.